# Using proc to duplicate parameters in Tcl

Tags: tcl, proc-object

I want to make several objects, all with the same parameters, so I tried to store them in a proc that returns them. But the interpreter evaluates the returning result as one parameter, instead of several. my proc is:

```
proc element_param {} {
    return "-filled 1\
        -visible 1\
        -linewidth 1\
        -linecolor yellow\
        -fillcolor yellow\
        -relief roundraised\
        -linewidth 2"
}
```

and I use it with:

```
$this/zinc add rectangle 1 [list "100" "100" "200" "200"] [element_param]
```

How do I turn them into several different parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With tcl 8.5 and above use the {*} operator to expand the list of parameters:

```
$this/zinc add rectangle 1 $coords {*}[element_param]
```

with previous versions you can expand lists using eval:

```
eval [linsert [element_param] 0 $this/zinc add rectangle 1 $coords]
```

which is equivalent.

Comment: Or: `eval [list $this/zinc add rectangle 1 $coords] [element_param]` since it is a list being returned, even if it is built in a horrible way.

Comment: @Donal Fellows, why is it built in a horrible way, and what is a better way to build it?

Comment: @Ilya: It's better to use the `list` command, since that does the right thing with quoting if you decide you need options with a space in (for example). While it is possible to quote those things by hand, this is **strongly discouraged** because it's easy to get wrong; use `list` (or one of the other commands that makes a list) and have it done correctly for you, automatically.